# libpng warning in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, png, libpng

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Eclipse 3.7.2 trying to use MathGL.
My simple, c++ looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mgl2/mgl.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

 mglGraph gr;
 gr.FPlot("sin(pi*x)");
 gr.WritePNG("test.png");

return 0;
}
```

When I run it I get the following warning :

```
libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.46 but running with 1.5.13
```

And test.png cannot be displayed.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-build you app to use libpng-1.5.13. Currently it is built with 1.2.46. Or you could read the release notes for the 2 versions and determine what is supported in 1.2.46 and stay within those boundaries. You must be trying to use functionality in lidpng that is not in 1.2.46